# Sharepoint PowerShell Library Folder permissions

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

I’m new to both SharePoint (2010) and PowerShell (and Microsoft in general. Linux was my thing. I’ve decided to come to the dark side for a while :) ). Anyway, how do you set permissions for a specific user, for a specific folder, within another specific folder, for a specific library in SharePoint, using PowerShell?
For Example. 
 “Meetings” (Library)
       --> IT Services (Folder)
             -->Incidents (sub Folder)
          -->December2012 (sub Folder) Grant “Read Only” access to “Tim Smith”

(in other words, in the Library "Meetings", there is a folder "IT services", in that is a folder "Incidents", and in that folder is another folder called "December2012")

Yes, I can just do it manually from the GUI, but I will need to do this a number of times (different folders and different users). I can spit out a list of all the folders (and sub folders) for a library; I’m just not sure what commend to run, to assign the permission on that folder, for a given user.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

There is plenty of info about Powershell and SharePoint 2010, particularly good books if you are doing this often.  For a one-off, try this:
http://sharepoint2010tutor.blogspot.com.au/2011/08/grant-folder-permissionsharepoint-using.html